# When importing dependency for e2e ionic 2

Tags: angular, protractor, ionic2

I followed this link to test a sample starter app
http://lathonez.github.io/2016/ionic-2-e2e-testing/ 
it worked good when i test with empty starter app but when i was trying to integrate this to my project i get issue like this

```
yokeshs-Mac-mini:easy yokesh$ node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile test/gulpfile.ts --cwd ./ test.build
[11:42:51] Requiring external module ts-node/register
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
app/pages/soLogin/business-partner-location.ts (5,22): Cannot find module './config'. (2307)
app/pages/soLogin/business-partner-location.ts (6,28): Cannot find module './user;'. (2307)
app/pages/soLogin/business-partner-location.ts (6,36): Unterminated string literal. (1002)
app/providers/orderline-service.ts (6,27): Cannot find module './user-service'. (2307)
app/providers/orderline-service.ts (7,28): Cannot find module './order-service'. (2307)
    at getOutput (/Users/yokesh/easy/node_modules/ts-node/src/ts-node.ts:210:13)
    at Object.loader (/Users/yokesh/easy/node_modules/ts-node/src/ts-node.ts:225:23)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/Users/yokesh/easy/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/Users/yokesh/easy/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:193:16)
    at module.exports (/Users/yokesh/easy/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/Users/yokesh/easy/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:185:9)
yokeshs-Mac-mini:easy yokesh$ 


yokeshs-Mac-mini:easy yokesh$ ionic info
WARN: ionic.config.js has been deprecated, you can remove it.
```

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.22
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.12
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

could some one help to fix this, for e2e testing